# How can I fetch my friend's Facebook friend list using his/her Facebook id in C#?

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, c#-4.0

Is it possible to fetch my friend's friend list using his Facebook id?  I am able to fetch my own friend list in a grid but now I want to fetch their friend list on the basis of their Facebook user id.

Comment: May be some javascript that iterates over grid and loads 'sub-friends'?

Answer (score 2):

You cant. Facebook api only provide friend list info for the logged user.

If you try it you will get a message like:

```
   {
       "error": {
          "type": "Exception",
          "message": "(#604) Can't lookup all friends of <UID>. Can only lookup for the logged in user (<MY_UID>), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission"
       }
    }
```

If you want to do it you will have to do it by yourself parsing html and that stuff, but out of the facebook Graph Api

If you require the appropriate extended permission when the users authorize your app, you can access some data of the currently logged user's friends, but that's all you get .

(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions see: friends_xxxx permissions), but not his/her friends.

Comment: and quite frankly, for good reason. FB Apps provide enough spam already